# How to append js variable to dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append the contents of a variable to a div. The variable to append is selected based on the name the `value` of the `<a>` that is clicked (e.g. `<a value="shops">`).

In other words, if someone clicks a link and it has the value `shops` this function should append the contents of the variable `shopsGrid` to the div `.places`.

Please keep in mind that I am a very junior developer. Thanks!

```
var sweetsGrid = $('.places>div.sweets');
var shopsGrid = $('.places>div.shops'); 

// second variable shopsGrid above just to 
// clarify there are lots of these variables written 
// out to select from 

$(".filters>.btn.labelz").click(function(){

  var selection = $(this).attr( "value" );
  $(''+selection+'Grid').appendTo('.places');
  // the line above is the one that doesn't work :(

});
```

```js
 var grid = $('.places>div');
 var sweetsGrid = $('.places>div.sweets');
 var shopGrid = $('.places>div.drink');
 var eatGrid = $('.places>div.eat');
 

 $(".filters>.btn.labelz").click(function(){

   var selection = $(this).attr( "data-value" );

   if($('.label-all').hasClass('active')){
     $('.label-all').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
     $('.filters>.btn.labelz').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
     $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
     $('.places>div:not(.'+selection+')').detach();
   } else {
     if($(this).hasClass('active')){
       $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
       $('.places>div.'+selection+'').detach();
     } else {
       $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
       // THIS IS THE ISSUE!
       $(selection+'Grid').appendTo('.places');

     }
   }

   

   return false;
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="GUIDE">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>NYC GUIDE</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">





  </head>

  <body>


    <div class="row" id="navbar">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified filters">
          <a href="#" class="labelz label-eat btn active" data-value="Eat">Eat</a>
          <a href="#" class="labelz label-chill btn active" data-value="chill">Chill</a>
          <a href="#" class="labelz label-drink btn active" data-value="drink">Drink</a>
          <a href="#" class="labelz label-fashion btn active" data-value="fashion">Fashion</a>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container" id="places-wrapper">
      <div class="row places all-places">
        <div class="col-sm-4 place drink eat">
          <h5 class="tags"><span class="label label-drink">Drink</span><span class="label label-eat">Eat</span></h5>
          <h3>Place 1</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 place fashion">
          <h5 class="tags"><span class="label label-fashion">Fashion</span></h5>
          <h3>Place 2</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 place fashion">
          <h5 class="tags"><span class="label label-chilll">chill</span></h5>
          <h3>Place 3</h3>
        </div>

    </div>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA6eMmlCy8MX-p6Imo0scPRWj6D0MCl1y0&&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That should work, *provided* the elements you're hooking exist as of your call to `click`. (Doing it too soon is a common error. For instance, if your `script` is in the `head` -- an anti-pattern you see far too often -- then the elements won't exist. Put the `script` just before the closing `</body>` tag if that's the problem.) Can you post an [MCVE](/help/mcve) (preferably using a Stack Snippet) to the question demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Side note: `value` is not a valid attribute for `a` elements. To put arbitrary data in attributes, use the `data-` prefix (e.g., `data-value`).

Comment: Side note 2: You don't need or want the `''+` before `selection+'Grid'` on your `appendTo` line. It's harmless, but pointless. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! I added the snippet and your suggested edit but still not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such attribute `value` for anchors. As a workaround, (pointed by @T.J. Crowder) you can make use of HTML5 `data-*` attributes to store arbitrary data to *any* DOM element.

**HTML**

```
<a data-value="the-link-value"></a>
```

**JS**

```
$(".filters>.btn.labelz").click(function(){    
     var selection = $(this).data( "value" );
     $(selection+'Grid').appendTo('.places');
});
```

You can access the arbitrary set data using jQuery's `.data()` method as well as the common `.attr()` method for attributes.

**Note:** Although you can use `.data()` here to serve your purpose of getting the arbitrary set data. But do remember that if `.data()` is used to store data in key-value pairs (e.g. `$(selector).data('key', 'value')`) to the DOM, then only `.data()` itself can be used to fetch it back (i.e. `$(selector).data('key')`). Using `.attr()` in this case is pointless and will only work on *embedded* HTML5 `data-*` attributes.

***Update***

I tried to emulate your code in JSfiddle and noticed that you are using a *string concatination* to refer a Javascript variable. Assuming the `selection` variable has the value`fashion` in it, then `selection+'Grid'` will always evaluate to the string `fashionGrid` and NOT the variable `fashionGrid`.

I have two suggestions as workarounds for your problem:

1. Use Javascript's [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method to enforce treating the string `selection + 'Grid'` to refer the actual variable.

   ```
   $(eval(selection+'Grid')).appendTo('.places');
   ```
2. > eval() is also generally slower than the alternatives, since it has to invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized by modern JS engines. There are safer (and faster!) alternatives to eval() for common use-cases.

The above quoted from MDN is one of many reasons which discourage use of `eval()`. As a better approach, avoiding `eval`, you could make use of Javascript objects instead:

```
    var grid = {}; 
    grid['fashion'] = $('.fashion');  // add another object in `fashion` key to the grid
    grid['eat'] = $('.eat'); // add another object in `eat` key to the grid
```

Then, access the particular `selector` value in an object key as such:

```
    $(grid[selection]).appendTo('.places');
```

*A brief [JSfiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/5gg6azs8/2/) to help you better understand the two approaches.*

Comment: Very helpful notes, but in the snippet I attached the variables are not inserted back into the dom. If you click, for example, the link "fashion" in the snippet once it correctly removes all the elements _except_ for those with the class `fashion` from the DOM, and it removes the elements with the class `fashion` you click it again (correctly adding the class `inactive` to the `a` tag), but when you click it a third time it does not add the specific variable `fashionGrid` back to the DOM (which should contain the html corresponding to all the `divs` with the class `fashion`?

Comment: @SahadevaHammari, have a look at the updated answer. The real problem with your code was that you're confusing a _string_ with an evaluation of the string as a _variable_.

Comment: Ah! This helps so much [and it work]! I had an inkling that something like this might be happening, and helps conceptually a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

change this line:

```
    $(''+selection+'Grid').appendTo('.places');
```

to

```
    $(selection+'Grid').appendTo('.places');
```